# Regular expression to get value

Tags: javascript

I was wondering how I would go about getting the value from this string:

```
LUGG::1::LUGG::5-GBP
```

In this case, the value retrieved would be "**1**".

Comment: `value.split('::')[1]`

Comment: This got nothing to do with jQuery

Comment: Perfect @adeneo thanks :) (If you add it as an answer I'll mark it)

Comment: @adeneo Why are you escaping the colons? `"LUGG::1::LUGG::5-GBP".match(/::(.*?)::/)[1]` works fine.

Comment: @h2ooooooo - cause I'm just that good

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's hard to say for certain without knowing all the possible options of input strings, but for example if you always just want to get the number that has `::` on its left AND `::` on its right (`1` in your example):

```
var myInput = 'LUGG::1::LUGG::5-GBP';

var myNumber = myInput.match(/::(\d+)::/)[1];

alert(myNumber); // alerts 1
```